# Enumerable.Any method is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, elasticlinq

I have this code :

```
var jobs3 = _provider.Context.Query<JobResults>()
                     .Where(m => m.Groups.Any(y => userGroups.Contains(y.GroupName)))
                     .ToList();
```

This method gives me exception in the title. How can I fix this? Is there a way to run this method without using Any? Thanks.

Comment: What LINQ provider do you use?

Comment: What is the type of the `Groups` member?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev ElasticLinq

Comment: @Codor It's a custom object that includes a string which is GroupName.

Comment: Looks like the second method is unrelated, you'd better remove it. What about the question, looks like your query provider does not support such type of query expression.

Comment: What is about using Count() > 0 instead of Any(). I know it could be slower  but it should work.

Comment: See if that helps [Custom queries with ElasticMethods](https://github.com/ElasticLINQ/ElasticLINQ/wiki/Getting-Started#custom-queries-with-elasticmethods)

Comment: @IvanChepikov I tried `Count() > 0` and I had to use `Where`. But it looks like `Where` is not supported either.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have tried ContainsAny method but I couldn't, can you see a way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by converting IQueryable to List, process the list and  then convert it back to the IQueryable.

Comment: There's no "going back to the database" once you've materialized the query into an in-memory collection.  You're pulling the entire table down into memory and doing *all* of the processing in-memory if you're doing this.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I'm doing this. Now I realized how inefficient it is, especially with big data. But I couldn't find any other way. Do you have any suggestion?